# Do I need jsp or php when I use extjs as my frontend technology?

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

I ever developed front-end pages using JSP. I will embed **jquery.js** into the JSP pages. If I changed to EXTJS which I know is rich client technology. Do I need JSP as well?
Or EXTJS is enough to act as the front-end role?
PS: I plan to use servlet as the back-end service.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually I want to konw the best practice of extjs. In other words, How is the extjs being used by most developers? Is it used alone or with other dynamic language like php,jsp?

Comment: Before someone can answer that, we need to know exactly what you need to display and how your system is going to work. ExtJS is perfectly capable of handling the whole front end by itself but sometimes you may have to mix it with Jsp or PHP or whatever you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it if you have all of your data up front and don't need to store anything.

Otherwise, it doesn't really matter what back end you use since the interchange is all JSON.

I use it extensively with an asp.net MVC back end. I'm a big fan, but the learning curve had me swearing at it for a while. You really have to study the documentation and examples or you'll end up taking the long cut on things. Everything you need to do is there, so much so that finding it can be tough.